# Ubuntu won't boot from my Sony vaio SSD laptop

Tags: ssd, sony

I have tried booting ubuntu 14.04 with DVD, but screen just goes black and stuck on vaio icon, nothing happens.

Is there a problem with my SSD (is sony ultra book)? Wasn't sure if I had windows virus as windows behaving funny and lost internet connection. Could virus stop ubuntu from booting?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Anything on hard-drive shouldn't effect booting from DVD. Even if there is a virus on windows, it will not work on Ubuntu either. So you should try to see if your ubuntu 14.04 installation DVD is defective or not by booting on other laptop or try to create a bootable Ubuntu USB memory stick.